# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.9 jspdf

Tags: angular, angular5, jspdf, html-to-pdf

**How can i install jspdf ??**

```
F:\project\jobs-fair\recruiter-webapp\angularApp>npm install jspdf --save
```

> F:\project\jobs-fair\recruiter-webapp\angularApp
>   +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.9
>   +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@5.2.9 `-- jspdf@1.3.5
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
>   (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.2
>   (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.2
>   (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a
>   peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but
>   none was installed.

*package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.2",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.0.480",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "xlsx": "^0.12.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
```

Comment: The error `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.9` means you need to update your package.json to reference the @Angular packages at version 5.2.9 e.g. `"@angular/animations": "^5.2.9"`. I would recommend updating ALL of the @angular packages to 5.2.9

Comment: i installed all latest packages

Comment: I have managed to create a new angular app and instal jspdf without seeing that error. I siggest you delete your ‘node_modules’ folder and run ‘npm i’ to reinstall them all.

Answer (score 0):

I too was getting **UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@6.1.1 invalid** error whenever i tried to install any other package(eg. npm install angular4-datepicker).

My **npm -v was 3.x.x** . So i upgraded my npm to **5.6.0** by installing the latest node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/  and it fixed the above issue for me.